# How to make the concept of a default button accessible on the web?

Tags: html, accessibility, user-experience, screen-readers, wai-aria

Desktop applications have a concept of default button. To quote the [OS X HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-BABCAJID) (the concept exists across the board but with different visual styling):

> ”Usually the rightmost button or the Cancel button is the default button. A default button has color and pulses to let the user know that when they press Return or Enter, the default button is activated.“

Now this visually separate button, when used appropriately, is a good aid to the user. A button on the web can be styled to look and behave like a default button. However, **how do I convey this extra information to users who can’t see the styling?**

In OS X, VoiceOver—the screenreader—will say “Cancel, default, button. Delete Everything, button.” Clearly identifying available options and what is the suggested action. I was hoping WAI-ARIA had something to offer, but I can’t find anything that looks even remotely applicable.

The closest analogy I have found in HTML is `input[type=submit]`, though it does not seem to have any meaning in WAI-ARIA and strictly does not have an applicable meaning in HTML either.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for you to deal with this would be to add some "off screen text", to the button's label so that the extra role information is read out.

Using an <input> means that you essentially have to have some text hidden somewhere on the page with a unique id attribute on that element and point to it by placing aria-describedby on the input element with the value of the id attribute in the aria-describedby attribute.